# Ntop Python API

Tags: python

Can anyone point me towards tutorials for using the Python API in Ntop (other than that Luca Deris paper)?

In web interfaces there is `about > online documentation > python engine` but I think this link has an error. Does anyone have access to that document to re-post online for me?

Answer (score 3):

If you have ntop installed you can look at the example files in `/usr/share/ntop/python` (that's where they're at in the Ubuntu package version, at least).

If you have `epydoc` installed you can run `make` from within the  `/usr/share/ntop/python/docs` directory to generate the documentation. Once you do that the `About > Online Documentation > Python ntop Engine > Python API` link will work correctly (it seems like a bug that it requires work on the part of the user to fix that link).